# Get number of github downloads

Tags: github, get

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Github API to get the number of downloads of a release. I have a test repo called `polymer-reptation` under my username `benlindsay` with one tag, `1.0`. A Github Developer page [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release) says that to get the information on a single release I can use the command `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id`. I can't figure out how to use that command though. I tried things like `curl --user "benlindsay" https://api.github.com/repos/:benlindsay/:polymer-reptation/releases/:1.0` on the command line, the same thing without the colons, and typing similar things into [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/). They all just give me

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",       
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

at best. Can someone show me to how to use this feature of the API? (an easier way to track downloads would be helpful as well if one exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it without the colons, they are there to indicate stuff you should replace.

However, Listing all releases at `https://api.github.com/repos/benlindsay/polymer-reptation/releases` Returns an empty array... No releases My guess is the API hasn't caught up yet. If this doesn't resolve itself shortly, contact GitHub.

Comment: OK, so maybe at least some of my attempts were correct ways of doing it. Followup question: `https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases` correctly gets the TensorFlow releases, but the releases don't have any "assets", which is where the `download_count` field would be. Furthermore, `https://api.github.com/repos/vim/vim/releases` returns an empty array even though there are thousands of releases. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @BenLindsay Ah, right. The assets tag is only present when you have uploaded binaries to go with the release. The `download_count` indicates download of that binary. `https://api.github.com/repos/vim/vim/releases` Is blank because they have only created tags to indicate releases, not "full" releases themselves.